# How to write a letter to change my travel information

Tags: grammar, meaning, word-usage

So, I was writing a letter to change my departure date and time for a bus trip, and I was so confused about this grammar structure. Since the staff already asked me to confirm the dates/ times I wish to change my booking to, Do I not have to mention the word ‘date’ and ‘time’ again but can just say like

> I'd love to change it to July 6th, 15:30pm

Or would it be better for me to mention them again and say like

> I'd love to change my departure date to July 6th and the time to 15:30pm

What would be the most natural way to reply?

Comment: There's nothing wrong or unnatural about either sentence, other than the fact that Americans (who aren't in the military) don't use 24-hour time -- and if you do use 24-hour time, you don't have to specify am or pm.  So it's either **15:30** or **2:30 pm**.

Comment: Anyway, which you choose is personal preference and circumstance.  You may have noticed the staff are, shall we say, "easily confused", and so you want to make your requested change as clear as possible.

Comment: @Andrew: You mean 3:30pm.

Comment: @TimPederick #doh! #headslap

Answer (score 1):

The second form is a lot more literal and awkward in day-day speak. Your first example is what I'd consider "normal" for casual speaking.

Another way to say it would be to say

> “I'd love to change my departure time to July 6th, 15:30pm”

You don't have to explicitly state that you're changing both the date and time- that'd be implied by the date/time that you give them.